# Makefile 'for' variable as dynamic variable name

Tags: makefile

I have some dynamically named variables in Makefile. That all works and is fine. 
Now I need to reference some of those variables in a for loop, but I can't seem to find the right syntax:

```
@for module in $(MODULES); do \
    (echo $(SRC_$$module)); \
done
```

each $(MODULE) is a name that needs to be appended to $(SRC_.. for example $(SRC_foo) $(SRC_bar)... but I can't seem to do that with this syntax.

Comment: Could you propose an alternative solution then? How could I build a list at make time then? For each $(MODULES) get $(SRC_$$module)) and make a list out of that.

Comment: `$(foreach module,$(MODULES), \
 $(foreach cfile, $(SRC_$(module)), \
  $(shell echo "$(cfile)") \
 ) \
)` for some reason this doesn't loop through $(MODULES)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have expansion-time issues. You can't expand make-level variables dynamically once the shell has started to run. Which is what you are trying to do here.

You either expand the variables at make time or at shell time but not both.

To expand everything at make time you can use something like this.

```
@$(foreach module,$(MODULES),$(foreach cfile,$(SRC_$(module)),echo '[$(cfile)]';))
```

Expanding at shell time is possible but a bit messier/trickier.

Comment: You could've left the comments, it wouldn't matter! Thanks again though!